# MYSQL script import error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an error when I try to import data through the command:

```
mysql -u root -p"root" cvdb < "cvdb.sql"
```

The error I am getting is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 72: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(14) NOT NULL,
>     `Created` datetime NOT NULL default ' 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ',
>     ' at line 14

The code of my SQL file is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `activity`;
CREATE TABLE `activity` (
  `AllDay` enum('YES','NO') default 'NO',
  `ActivityID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Type` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Priority` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Status` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `DueDate` datetime default NULL,
  `CompletedDate` datetime default NULL,
  `Details` text,
  `Creator` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Owner` int(11) default NULL,
  `ModifiedBy` int(11) default NULL,
  `Modified` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  `Created` datetime NOT NULL default ' 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ',
  `Start` datetime default NULL,
  `End` datetime default NULL,
  `AttachmentType` enum('NONE','FILE','LINK') NOT NULL default 'NONE',
  `Location` varchar(25) default NULL,
  `visibility` enum('PRIVATE','PUBLIC') NOT NULL default 'PRIVATE',
  `Notes` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ActivityID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ActivityID` (`ActivityID`),
  KEY `Type` (`Type`),
  KEY `Priority` (`Priority`),
  KEY `Status` (`Status`),
  KEY `Creator` (`Creator`),
  KEY `Owner` (`Owner`),
  KEY `ModifiedBy` (`ModifiedBy`),
  KEY `Location` (`Location`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is here `Modified timestamp(14) NOT NULL`. you should remove `(14)` from timestamp.

your partial `DDL`,

```
  `ModifiedBy` int(11) default NULL,
  `Modified` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `Created` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
  `Start` datetime default NULL,
```

Answer (score 0):

From [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) doc

> Incompatible change: In very old versions of MySQL (prior to 4.1), the
>   TIMESTAMP data type supported a display width, which was silenty
>   ignored beginning with MySQL 4.1. This is deprecated in MySQL 5.1, and
>   removed altogether in MySQL 5.5. These changes in behavior can lead to
>   two problem scenarios when trying to use TIMESTAMP(N) columns with a
>   MySQL 5.5 or later server:
>
> ...
>
> **You should try to handle potential issues of these types proactively
>   by updating with ALTER TABLE any TIMESTAMP(N) columns in your
>   databases so that they use TIMESTAMP instead, before performing any
>   upgrades.**

So try to remove the `(14)`
in

```
Modified timestamp(14) NOT NULL
```

or as said in doc, try to make `alter table` statements on your timestamp columns before import.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick reply. it really worked i was searching for 3 hours and u replied in 3 min thanks once again..

Comment: @user1948334 no prob, answer edited, by the way, it might be usefull.